# date type column returning date and time values

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a table with a column where I store dates (2015/10/10 for example), the column is `date` datatype, not `datetime`. But when I execute a query selecting the date value and converting it to string with `ExecuteScalar()` in C# to display it on a TextBox I get date and time.

This is my query:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select guaranty_date from telephone where ID_telephone = '"vaue"' ");

Text1Box.Text = cmd.ExcecuteScalar().ToString();
```

but I'm getting this result in the text box: `10/10/2015 12:00:00 a. m.`

Why is that?

Comment: is it working without error `"select guaranty_date from telephone where ID_telephone = '"vaue"' "` because Date it showing in C# not SQL

Comment: First you should bind parameters, then you should cast result

Comment: if u want to save 2015/10/10 just change the column type to text (nvarchar)

Comment: @cyan this is a teribble advice. the Date data type is the only appropriate data type to keep date only values.

Comment: The .NET Framework doesn't have a `Date` datatype - only `DateTime`. So even if your SQL Server table only stores `DATE`, in .NET, you always have `DateTime` for that.

Comment: @cyan Oh, please, no, do not ever suggest that again (and even if it were a good idea to store dates as strings, which it is absolutely not, it is even worse to use `nvarchar` - do you know of any dates with Unicode characters in them?).

Comment: There is no problem or bug here. .NET has no date-only type, it only has DateTime and DateTimeOffset. If you want to render only the date portion of the DateTime, you need to specify the appropriate format string, eg `d` for the locale specific short date pattern

Comment: @cyan, please stop advicing to store dates as text in SQL Server. It's a terrible bad practice.

Comment: hehehe ok... i always use @Zohar's solution to do the job done ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date data type does not keep time. The problem is the default string representation of `DateTime` in c#.
Try this:

```
Text1Box.Text = ((DateTime)cmd.ExcecuteScalar()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: The problem isn't the "default" implementation (there isn't any, it's locale and user specific). It's that there is no Date-only type

Comment: Well, that's what I mean by "default". But you are correct, I should have elaborated more.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem or bug here. .NET has no date-only type, it only has DateTime and DateTimeOffset. You can say that this omission is almost a Framework bug, and in fact there is an [OSS project](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) going on that aims to add such types to .NET.

If you want to render only the date portion of the DateTime, you need to specify the appropriate format string, eg d for the locale specific short date pattern:

```
DateTime result=cmd.ExcecuteScalar();
Text1Box.Text = result.ToString("d");
```

You can check the various standard date formats in [Standard Date and Time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to use a specific format, no matter what the user's/thread's locale is, you need to use a [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), eg:

```
Text1Box.Text = result.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The reason I passed `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is that `/` is the date separator placeholder. In some cultures (eg German), this is `-` or `.`. It's become almost a SO tradition to mention this potential pitfall.

Comment: I did'nt know that, thanks for your very good explanation about this and the code!

Answer (score 0):

There is no CLR type that match exactly to SQL Server `date` type. SQL Server `date` type is mapped to CLR `DateTime` type. `DateTime` type represents a point in time, not only the day, so when you call DateTime.ToString() it also shows the time part. But if you know the time part is irrelevant, you can use another overload of DateTime.ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, C# doesn't include a "date-only" datatype. If this is just for displaying the value, you could alter the query to return the date formated the way you want:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select convert(char(10),guaranty_date,103) as guaranty_date from telephone where ID_telephone = '"vaue"' ");
Text1Box.Text = cmd.ExcecuteScalar().ToString();
```

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) you can find the possible date-formats